# Nodejs stream (Error: Can't set headers after they are sent)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to build an api from the braintree servers. Referring to this doc https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/reference/general/result-handling/search-results

To access all the transactions from their server I have to return a node stream.

ex

```
app.get('/project', function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {

      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
        search.customerId().is(req.user.id);
      });

      stream.on("ready", function () {
        console.log(stream.searchResponse);
      });

      stream.on("data", function (data) {
        res.json(data) // can't set headers after they are sent. 
      });

  }
});
```

I understand a stream returns data in chunks, so the `res.json()` above is most likely is being called multiple times resulting in `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.

So my question is how can I send that data to the client in one chunk? The nodejs streaming is confusing to me, I am going to read up more about it, but it would be great to understand how to send the data to the client without re-sending the headers.

Comment: `res.json()` is meant to be used as a single response and it ends the response.  It can't be called more than once on the same request/response.  It also typically can't be used on arbitrary chunks of data since it requires a fully formed piece of javascript data in order to be able to render legal JSON.

Comment: Yeah, I get that to an extent but my question is how do I take that data within, the `.on('data')` callback and send that data to the client. Maybe I should improve my vanilla javascript skills and build a function out of the call back or something then use `res.json()` inside the stream `.on('end')` callback?

Comment: Also, do you really want to send JSON to the client or do you just want to stream the results to the client?  I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well my app has a section where clients can review their transactions, and so I am building a model, or perhaps a collection  on the client side javascript. So I need to make an ajax request, therefore need json. So to answer your question, I doubt the client fetch method will work very good if the data is streaming?

Comment: I wish braintree wouldnt have made it a stream, I get it if the data is going to be big, but they have a perfect method here `gateway.transaction.find("theTransactionId", function (err, transaction) {
});` but I can't use a transactonId I need to search by customerId

Comment: Can't I just use the `on('end')` callback. I mean isn't there a way to wait for the data chunks to fully load then return that data as a whole?

Comment: Yes, you can collect the data on each `"data"` event and then send it all on the `"end"` event.  Sorry, I can't help more specifically because I don't understand what the format of the data is or exactly what part of that you want to send to the client or in what format you want to send it to the client.  If you want the entire thing to go to the client exactly as it comes out of the stream and it's already JSON, you can probably just `.pipe()` one stream into another with one line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't make any assumptions about `data` events unless the stream you are reading from is in object mode. You could get one `data` event or a hundred (depending on the input size of course) because TCP is a stream.

What you probably want is something like this instead (assuming `stream` is not in object mode):

```
app.get('/project', function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {

      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
        search.customerId().is(req.user.id);
      });

      stream.on("ready", function () {
        console.log(stream.searchResponse);
      });

      var buf = '';
      stream.on("data", function (data) {
        buf += data;
      });

      stream.on("end", function() {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(buf);
      });

  }
});
```

Or just pipe the stream to the response:

```
app.get('/project', function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {

      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
        search.customerId().is(req.user.id);
      });

      stream.on("ready", function () {
        console.log(stream.searchResponse);
      });

      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      stream.pipe(res);
  }
});
```

For an object stream you might do:

```
app.get('/project', function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {

      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
        search.customerId().is(req.user.id);
      });

      stream.on("ready", function () {
        console.log(stream.searchResponse);
      });

      var result = [];
      stream.on("data", function (data) {
        result.push(data);
      });

      stream.on("end", function() {
        res.json(result);
      });

  }
});
```

Comment: Great stuff, I keep seeing piping but this really helps put it into context. It makes sense, let me try it out.

Comment: The first method seems to have worked, second method I got an error. I do like the first method, but I get `[object Object][object Object]` so obviously there are two objects(transactions) on the braintree server. So how do I return those as an array of objects and not `[object Object][object Object]` thats such a noob question but my vanilla javascript could use some work.

Comment: I reproduced what is going on here http://jsfiddle.net/b30c7ady/ I think that closely resembles what is going on. I may have to open a new question specifically for this, but I would like to know why I am getting `[object Object]`. I can mess with the fiddle at least, and I don't have to worry about restarting my server over and over and re-logging in, so that's good.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it's an object stream then. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah okay, wow I didn't think to use `push`. Thanks you were a big help.